# How to check if contents of string qualify as a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to make a C# .NET core console application that can run like a simple command line OS. (not an actual OS just a mimic). I would like to check if the contents of a string that I have as a variable would qualify as a string themselves. If need-be I can write my own parser thingy, but I would much prefer a simpler solution.

I have not tried anything, because I have no idea whatsoever of how to even go about starting.

Comment: "would quality as a string themselves"? What does that mean?

Comment: Erm, the contents or a string always qualify as a string. Can you give us one or more examples of what you have and what would or would not be acceptable?

Comment: For example, I would like to test if `"Hello world"` would qualify as a string, but the variable I have is equal to `"\"Hello world\""` Because it is a console program, users enter one line at a time. I need to be able to tell if that line would qualify as a string.

Comment: They're both still strings. What do you NOT want to see, and why?

Comment: Anything qualifies as a string in .NET, it's all a question of how you represent it. I suppose you mean whether the user input is valid in the context of your 'command line'; to check that, you will need a parser. You can write one from scratch, or use one of the available libraries for it. For writing a parser from scratch, you may also want to look into using F#, which makes things such as writing a parser much easier than C#.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to write a parser and there was a simple way, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @SteveTodd I am hoping to see that `"\"Hello world\""` would qualify but `"1"` or `"true"` would not.

Comment: Look at the TryParse() methods for bool, int and probably double. If any of them can parse your string then you have a fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you're looking for something like this: https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils .. It allows you to parse the command line and call off different methods depending on the input?

Comment: Thanks! I still dont really understand how to use this, but its a great starting point that I can probably come to understand eventually.